# transfer jpg excel to power point python

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have 10 jpg files in sheet2 of excel, I need to transfer these images in power point in specific order. I am not sure if Range can copy the images? Please provide your opinion.

```
import win32com.client
ExcelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = False
workbook =ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\eshsubh\Documents\EKN\DL MS1.xlsx')
excelrange = worksheet.Range("A2:R24")
excelrange.Copy()
```